# unreachable` instruction executed when running overhead benchmark

Tags: runtime, wasm, runtime-api

for some reason running overhead benchmarks fails in our parachain.

```
cargo run --release --features=runtime-benchmarks benchmark overhead --chain local
```

results with following stacktrace

```
Error: Client(Application(Application(Execution(AbortedDueToTrap(MessageWithBacktrace { message: "wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed", backtrace: Some(Backtrace { backtrace_string: "
    0: 0x3fe0f6 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x664b - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h0a20ba97f16cb738
    2: 0x660c - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic::h20cc6242ae6ad8e6
    3: 0x26732d - <unknown>!<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime as sp_block_builder::runtime_decl_for_BlockBuilder::BlockBuilder<sp_runtime::generic::block::Block<sp_runtime::generic::header_ver::Header<u32,sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256>,sp_runtime::generic::unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<sp_runtime::multiaddress::MultiAddress<<<sp_runtime::MultiSignature as sp_runtime::traits::Verify>::Signer as sp_runtime::traits::IdentifyAccount>::AccountId,()>,mangata_kusama_runtime::Call,sp_runtime::MultiSignature,(frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>)>>>>::inherent_extrinsics::heebd5e387a87c636
    4: 0x398ecb - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_inherent_extrinsics
" }) })))))
```

Backtrace seems to pointing out to [BlockBuilderApi::inherent_extrinsics][1] runtime api call in [BlockBuilder::create_inherents][2]

```rust
    /// Create the inherents for the block.
    ///
    /// Returns the inherents created by the runtime or an error if something failed.
    pub fn create_inherents(
        &mut self,
        inherent_data: sp_inherents::InherentData,
    ) -> Result<Vec<Block::Extrinsic>, Error> {
        let block_id = self.block_id;
        self.api
            .execute_in_transaction(move |api| {
                // `create_inherents` should not change any state, to ensure this we always rollback
                // the transaction.
                TransactionOutcome::Rollback(api.inherent_extrinsics_with_context(
                    &block_id,
                    ExecutionContext::BlockConstruction,
                    inherent_data,
                ))
            })
            .map_err(|e| Error::Application(Box::new(e)))
    }
```

which seems to be very weird because both in [origin substrate runtime][3] and [our runtime][4] is same and depends on macro generated impl of [create_extrinsics][5]

```rust
    impl sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
        fn inherent_extrinsics(data: InherentData) -> Vec<<Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic> {
            data.create_extrinsics()
        }
    }
```

What is even more weird when i replace runtime impl of [BlockBuilder::inherent_extrinsics][0] with just some `panic`

it still produces the same error

```
  git diff
diff --git a/runtime/mangata-kusama/src/lib.rs b/runtime/mangata-kusama/src/lib.rs
index 087ece535..826cf78f5 100644
--- a/runtime/mangata-kusama/src/lib.rs
+++ b/runtime/mangata-kusama/src/lib.rs
@@ -1444,6 +1444,7 @@ impl_runtime_apis! {
                }
 
                fn inherent_extrinsics(data: sp_inherents::InherentData) -> Vec<<Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic> {
+                       panic!("blah blah");
                        data.create_extrinsics()
                }
 
  cargo run --release --features=runtime-benchmarks benchmark overhead --chain local
 ...
warning: `mangata-node` (lib) generated 15 warnings
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 2.67s
     Running `target/release/mangata-node benchmark overhead --chain local`
Error: Client(Application(Application(Execution(AbortedDueToTrap(MessageWithBacktrace { message: "wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed", backtrace: Some(Backtrace { backtrace_string: "
    0: 0x3fe0f6 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x664b - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h0a20ba97f16cb738
    2: 0x660c - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic::h20cc6242ae6ad8e6
    3: 0x26732d - <unknown>!<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime as sp_block_builder::runtime_decl_for_BlockBuilder::BlockBuilder<sp_runtime::generic::block::Block<sp_runtime::generic::header_ver::Header<u32,sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256>,sp_runtime::generic::unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<sp_runtime::multiaddress::MultiAddress<<<sp_runtime::MultiSignature as sp_runtime::traits::Verify>::Signer as sp_runtime::traits::IdentifyAccount>::AccountId,()>,mangata_kusama_runtime::Call,sp_runtime::MultiSignature,(frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>,pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<mangata_kusama_runtime::Runtime>)>>>>::inherent_extrinsics::heebd5e387a87c636
    4: 0x398ecb - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_inherent_extrinsics
" }) })))))
cargo run --release --features=runtime-benchmarks benchmark overhead --chain   16.96s user 1.19s system 417% cpu 4.351 total
```

so it feels like some problem with [sp_inherents::InherentData::create_inherents call][5] but with dispatching of runtime api calls?

**and yes i tried purging local chain data, purging cargo cache etc...**

> How to reproduce?

```
git clone git@github.com:mangata-finance/mangata-node.git
git checkout 35b5c154fe75f94c611f6e4d7f85e775d56c68ee
cargo run --release --features=runtime-benchmarks benchmark overhead --chain local
```

**It works fine when i force wasm method in benchmark config to be `WasmExecutionMethod::Interpreted` instead of `Compiled { instantiation_strategy: PoolingCopyOnWrite }`  but im not sure if its good enough for benchmarking overhead ?**

[1]: https://github.com/mangata-finance/substrate/blob/73c58904ba958bc9596e7a4624bf8c2afd99f111/primitives/block-builder/src/lib.rs#L45-L47ill go with interpreter for now to proceed with benchmarks, and try to
[2]: https://github.com/mangata-finance/substrate/blob/73c58904ba958bc9596e7a4624bf8c2afd99f111/client/block-builder/src/lib.rs#L279-L295
[3]: https://github.com/mangata-finance/substrate/blob/73c58904ba958bc9596e7a4624bf8c2afd99f111/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1774-L1776
[4]: https://github.com/mangata-It works fine when i force wasm method in benchmark config to be `WasmExecutionMethod::Interpreted` instead of `Compiled { instantiation_strategy: PoolingCopyOnWrite }`  but im not sure if its good enough for benchmarking overhead ?finance/mangata-node/blob/35b5c154fe75f94c611f6e4d7f85e775d56c68ee/runtime/mangata-kusama/src/lib.rs#L1446-L1448
[5]: https://github.com/mangata-finance/substrate/blob/73c58904ba958bc9596e7a4624bf8c2afd99f111/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/expand/inherent.rs#L48-L52

Comment: Thanks for putting in an *exact* commit hash and some commands on how to reproduce it. Otherwise the question would be very difficult to answer.

Comment: ahhh thank you! `--native` swtich was the thing! i can manage the other errors on my own

Comment: Please consider to mark the question as "Answered" if this solved your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is inherent data missing that the `parachain-system` pallet expects.
It needs to be added in your `inherent_benchmark_data` function which currently only injects timestamp data. The exact inherent data that is needed depends on your chain config.
Polkadot for example needs the para inherent data for a relay chain, whereas you need the para inherent data for a parachain.
Running the benchmarks with `--execution native` gets rid of any error stripping that happens in WASM.
If you add the changes below it will error on the next missing inherent data `Could not find AuRa author index`. So you also need to inject inherent data or [a pre-runtime digest](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12159) for Aura, not sure which of those.

```rust
/// Generates inherent data for the `benchmark overhead` command.
pub fn inherent_benchmark_data() -> Result<InherentData> {
    let mut inherent_data = InherentData::new();
    let d = Duration::from_millis(0);
    let timestamp = sp_timestamp::InherentDataProvider::new(d.into());

    timestamp
        .provide_inherent_data(&mut inherent_data)
        .map_err(|e| format!("creating inherent data: {:?}", e))?;

    // ADDED
    let mock_para_inherent_provider = cumulus_primitives_parachain_inherent::MockValidationDataInherentDataProvider {
        current_para_block: 0,
        relay_offset: 0,
        relay_blocks_per_para_block: 2,
        xcm_config: Default::default(),
        raw_downward_messages: Default::default(),
        raw_horizontal_messages: Default::default(),
    };

    mock_para_inherent_provider.provide_inherent_data(&mut inherent_data).expect("Mock must provide inherent data; qed");
    // END ADDED

    Ok(inherent_data)
}
```